# Openshift 1.4.1 and DNS Resolution

Tags: dns, openshift-origin, skydns

I'm installing Openshift for the first time an I need some help. I installed using the binary and it works, except when I want to do a build and it fails with the normal DNS Resolution Error(Just a test):

- OS: CentOS 7 updated, clean install, using network and not NetworkManager
- Openshift: Origin, Version 1.4.1
- Log from Build

`Cloning "https://github.com/openshift/cakephp-ex.git" ...
error: build error: fatal: unable to access       'https://github.com/openshift/cakephp-ex.git/': Could not resolve host:         github.com; Unknown error`

- Log from ocadm diagnostics

`

```
   ERROR: [DCli2012 from diagnostic DiagnosticPod@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/client/run_diagnostics_pod.       go:155]
   See the errors below in the output from the diagnostic pod:
   [Note] Running diagnostic: PodCheckAuth
          Description: Check that service account credentials authenticate as expected

   ERROR: [DP1003 from diagnostic PodCheckAuth@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/pod/auth.go:88]
          Could not authenticate to the master with the service account credentials: Get https://kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local:443/oapi/v1/users/~: dial tcp: lookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local: no such host

   ERROR: [DP1016 from diagnostic PodCheckAuth@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/pod/auth.go:113]
          DNS resolution for registry address docker-registry.default.svc.cluster.local returned an error; container DNS is likely incorrect. The error was: read udp 172.17.0.2:41440->172.30.0.21:53: read: no route to host

   [Note] Running diagnostic: PodCheckDns
          Description: Check that DNS within a pod works as expected

   ERROR: [DP2003 from diagnostic PodCheckDns@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/pod/dns.go:72]
          The first /etc/resolv.conf nameserver 172.30.0.21
          could not resolve kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local.
          Error: read udp 172.17.0.2:39189->172.30.0.21:53: read: no route to host
          This nameserver points to the master's SkyDNS which is critical for
          resolving cluster names, e.g. for Services.

   WARN:  [DP2014 from diagnostic PodCheckDns@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/pod/dns.go:119]
          A request to the nameserver 172.30.0.21 timed out.
          This could be temporary but could also indicate network or DNS problems.

   WARN:  [DP2015 from diagnostic PodCheckDns@openshift/origin/pkg/diagnostics/pod/dns.go:124]
          Error querying nameserver 172.30.0.21:
            read udp 172.17.0.2:35663->172.30.0.21:53: read: no route to host
          This may indicate a problem with DNS.

   [Note] Summary of diagnostics execution (version v1.4.1+3f9807a):
   [Note] Warnings seen: 2
   [Note] Errors seen: 3
```

`

- Doing some tests with dns and resolution on host:

`

```
dig github.com @172.30.0.21

; <<>> DiG 9.9.4-RedHat-9.9.4-38.el7_3.2 <<>> github.com @172.30.0.21
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 60788
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 2, AUTHORITY: 4, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;github.com.            IN  A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
github.com.     300 IN  A   192.30.253.113
github.com.     300 IN  A   192.30.253.112

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
github.com.     900 IN  NS  ns-1283.awsdns-32.org.
github.com.     900 IN  NS  ns-1707.awsdns-21.co.uk.
github.com.     900 IN  NS  ns-421.awsdns-52.com.
github.com.     900 IN  NS  ns-520.awsdns-01.net.

;; Query time: 34 msec
;; SERVER: 172.30.0.21#53(172.30.0.21)
;; WHEN: Mo Feb 27 11:50:29 CET 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 208
```

`

- Docker Configuration

  `ExecStart=/usr/bin/dockerd --dns 172.30.0.21 --storage-driver=overlay --insecure-registry 172.30.0.0/16`

Could someone help me? What I'm doing wrong?

I will appreciate any help, how I can fix it!

Thanks!

Comment: I think was already solved, I restarted the server and the configuration works!